# Does VSCode support CSS variables in react? error

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

This code work, but VSCode return error.

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <span  style={{"--backlight-color": "red"}} /* change color of span */ >text</span>,
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
:root {
  --backlight-color: silver; /* default color of span*/
}

span {
  background-color: var(--backlight-color);
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

This error is on line `<span  style={{"--backlight-color": "red"}} >text</span>,`:

> Types of property 'style' are incompatible.   Type '{
>   "--backlight-color": any; }' is not assignable to type
>   'CSSProperties'.     Object literal may only specify known properties,
>   and '"--backlight-color"' does not exist in type 'CSSProperties'.

Does VSCode support CSS variables in react?
How else should you implement it?

I do not want it to display this error in VScode.

It's about this bug:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6411

Comment: set `background-color:silver` insteadd of `--backlight-color: silver;`

Answer (score 0):

**You have to set**

```
root {
  background-color:silver;
}
```

**instead**

```
root {
  --backlight-color: silver;
}
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: No. This is default color of span. It's about the error VSCode shows.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is still an issue today. You can work around it by typecasting the custom property:

```
<span style={{ "--backlight-color": "red"}: as React.CSSProperties}>text</span>
```

> credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54128069/1783174)

If you need this in more then one place, I suggest you add it to the TS definitions as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70398145/1783174

Comment: I won't check because I haven't been using React lately.