# Trying to create circular progress using custom tailwind css library, but its not working

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

My goal is to build a circular progress indicator.

I have come across library daisyui and its `radial progress` component - https://daisyui.com/components/radial-progress/

it says: "Radial progress needs --value CSS variable to work."

I have tried doing this:

```
      <div className="radial-progress" style={{ "--value": 70 }}>
        70%
      </div>
```

But, it's not working, am I doing something wrong?

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

this is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tailwind-playground-forked-9jwc49?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Can you share whole file?

Comment: @cooskun yes, I added the link to the sandbox

Comment: Defining the variable in a style attribute in JSX might be your issue. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52005083/how-to-define-css-variables-in-style-attribute-in-react-and-typescript

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
const style = { "--value": 70 } as React.CSSProperties

<div className="radial-progress" style={style}>
  70%
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We package called `react-circular-progressbar` in react js we can use this to achieve your requirements.

(or)

we have multiple packages are there for circular progress bar you can choose which one is suited for you.

Comment: it's 72.5 kB in size, would that affect performance in general as opposed to just creating custom css?

Comment: refer https://codepen.io/juhaelee/pen/GxymWP for custom circular progress bar

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this issue with typescript.
I just added a `global.d.ts` file to the root folder of my project and use module augmentation to fix the issue

```
//global.d.ts
import React from "react";

declare module "react" {
  interface CSSProperties {
    "--value"?: string | number;
    "--size"?: string | number;
    "--thickness"?: string | number;
  }
}
```