# How can I add keyframe styling to React jsx file?

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to add an animation that requires me to use keyframe css.  Where can I add in my react file so I can also use a variable in it?

```
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-**Add variable from react); //ideally add react variable here
  }
}

.movement {
  animation: move 20s linear infinite;
}
```

JSX file/React JS File

```
function MovingCircle() {
   const size = 10; //variable I would like to use on top. It changes depending on other things going on on the page

   return (
      <div className="">circle</div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define css variables in style attribute in React and typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52005083/how-to-define-css-variables-in-style-attribute-in-react-and-typescript)

Comment: @Etheryte I get that you can do an inline style like style={{color:pink}}. I guess my question is how to you translate keyframes (multiline style) into it? Never seen it done

Comment: I would keep the style external as-is and use a [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) for the translate value, then define that variable with an inline style in React as shown in the above question.