# My custom css variables don't work inside css conic-gradient function. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, css-variables

So I am trying to build this custom component to indicate direction in a form of a pie chart,
where the direction is indicated by the chart's slice.

[image: My direction indicator]

I am using CSS to achieve this, but I only managed to make the slice static. I need the slice to change angles based on component props (start and end angles).

I am having troubles passing custom css variables to the element and making css conic-gradient function work with the given variables.

I don't know if it matters, but for the context, this is in React project, using MUI library with tailwind.

Below is my component:

(Notice how I set properties of the element by using plain document. Is this wrong? It feels wrong, but I didn't find other way, how to set custom css varaibles.)

```tsx
import "./DirectionIndicator.css";

type Props = {
    startAngle: number
    endAngle: number
}

export default function DirectionIndicator(props: Props) {

    const element = document?.getElementById("pieSlice")
    if (element) {
        element.style.setProperty("--startAngle", props.startAngle.toString())
        element.style.setProperty("--endAngle", props.endAngle.toString())
    }

    return (
        <div className={"pieContainer"}>
            <div className={"pieBackground"}>
                <div id="pieSlice" className={"slice"}/>
                <div className={"innerCircle"}>
                    <div className={"content"}>
                        <b>N</b>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and this is my css:

(Notice in class .slice there are two lines containing conic-gradient function. They are identical, except one is using the --startAngle and --endAngle variables instead of hardcoded values. When I use the line with hardcoded values, css works fine. When I switch for the one with variables, slice doesn't show. I don't understand what's wrong. I tried to remove setting the values in component via JS and use the default values from CSS file, but that doesn't work neither. Indicator remains empty.)

[image: Empty direction indicator]

```css
.pieContainer {
    height: var(--containerSize);
    position: relative;
    --containerSize: 100px;
    --innerCircleSize: 70px;
    --directionColor: #590;
    --innerCircleColor: #fff;
}

.pieBackground {
    position: absolute;
    width: var(--containerSize);
    height: var(--containerSize);
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.slice {
    --startAngle: 0;
    --endAngle: 12;
    transition: all 1000ms;
    width: var(--containerSize);
    height: var(--containerSize);
    border-radius: 100%;
    /*background: conic-gradient(from var(--startAngle)deg, var(--directionColor) var(--endAngle)deg, transparent 1deg);*/
    background: conic-gradient(from 60deg, var(--directionColor) 120deg, transparent 1deg);
}

.innerCircle {
    position: absolute;
    width: var(--innerCircleSize);
    height: var(--innerCircleSize);
    background-color: var(--innerCircleColor);
    border-radius: 100%;
    top:  calc((var(--containerSize) - var(--innerCircleSize)) / 2);
    left:  calc((var(--containerSize) - var(--innerCircleSize)) / 2);
    box-shadow: 2px 5px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset;
    color: black;
}

.innerCircle .content {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: var(--innerCircleSize);
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

I will be very grateful for any tips on how to fix this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (Notice how I set properties of the element by using plain document. Is this wrong?

It is wrong. You should set `style` attribute properties directly on the JSX element.

For the CSS, omit the `deg` suffix from the CSS variable values. When the CSS resolves, there is effectively always spaces surrounding `var()` functions. Thus the `conic-gradient()` value would become invalid. Instead, consider having the `deg` as part of the value in the React code:

```js
function DirectionIndicator(props) {
  const style = {
    '--startAngle': `${props.startAngle.toString()}deg`,
    '--endAngle': `${props.endAngle.toString()}deg`,
  };

  return (
    <div className={"pieContainer"}>
      <div className={"pieBackground"}>
        <div className={"slice"} style={style} />
        <div className={"innerCircle"}>
          <div className={"content"}>
            <b>N</b>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return <DirectionIndicator startAngle={90} endAngle={135} />
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```css
.pieContainer {
  height: var(--containerSize);
  position: relative;
  --containerSize: 100px;
  --innerCircleSize: 70px;
  --directionColor: #590;
  --innerCircleColor: #fff;
}

.pieBackground {
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--containerSize);
  height: var(--containerSize);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.slice {
  --startAngle: 0;
  --endAngle: 12;
  transition: all 1000ms;
  width: var(--containerSize);
  height: var(--containerSize);
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: conic-gradient(from var(--startAngle), var(--directionColor) var(--endAngle), transparent 1deg);
}

.innerCircle {
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--innerCircleSize);
  height: var(--innerCircleSize);
  background-color: var(--innerCircleColor);
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: calc((var(--containerSize) - var(--innerCircleSize)) / 2);
  left: calc((var(--containerSize) - var(--innerCircleSize)) / 2);
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
  color: black;
}

.innerCircle .content {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: var(--innerCircleSize);
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This worked! What a quick fix, you are legend. Before accepting the answer though, I am getting type error on the style. Is there way how to fix it?

TS2559: Type
{     '--startAngle': string;     '--endAngle': string; }
has no properties in common with type  Properties<string | number, string & {}> 
index.d.ts(1942, 9): The expected type comes from property  style  which is declared here on type
DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/65959390/19655631