Passing variable from React to CSS - proper formate and usage
I need to pass some data to a component to be used in CSS calculations. These calculations will depend upon breakpoints as well. It isn't working and I believe that the issue is that I don't know where to place the "px".
React Side
<MainMenu className={styles.mainMenu} myVar={ref1.current.clientHeight - ref2.current.clientHeight/>

CSS Side
.mainMenu {
   @include breakpoint(xlarge) {
      margin-top: var(--myVar)px;
      height: calc(100vh - var(--myVar)px);
  }
   @include breakpoint(small) {
      margin-top: var(--myVar - 47)px;
      height: calc(100vh - var(--myVar - 47)px);
  }
}


Try e.g. calc(100vh - (var(--myVar) * 1px)) - assuming myVar does not already have a unit associated with it.

look that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52005083/how-to-define-css-variables-in-style-attribute-in-react-and-typescript

You never set a value for --myVar in your document style.
You also cant write stuff like this var(--myVar)px and this var(--myVar - 47)px
The solution would be in the lines of:
React Side
const myVar = ref1.current.clientHeight - ref2.current.clientHeight;
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--myVar', `${myVar}px`);

CSS Side
.mainMenu {
    @include breakpoint(xlarge) {
       margin-top: var(--myVar);
       height: calc(100vh - var(--myVar));
   }
    @include breakpoint(small) {
       margin-top: calc(var(--myVar) - 47px);
       height: calc(100vh - var(--myVar) + 47px);
   }
 }

